# iptables src-range and dst-range

Tags: iptables

How do we use these flags with iptables? I keep getting invalid option/bad argument errors:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --src-range 192.168.25.149-192.168.25.151 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot "iprange" match.

This works:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.25.149-192.168.25.151 -j ACCEPT

http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x2702.html#TABLE.IPRANGEMATCH